# Finding the number of perfect squares in an array

Tags: swift, swift3

I am posting here for feedback about the code that I wrote to count the number of perfect squares in an array.

```
var arr = Array(4...17)
var count = 0
for i in arr{
  if Double(i).squareRoot().rounded() == Double(i).squareRoot(){
    count += 1
    }
}
print(count)
```

The result from the code is as expected. However, is this the "correct" way of doing? Or is there a "better" way of doing it? I did a coding test from a tech recruiting website (platform) and although the result is as expected, but the website gave me 0% on the "correctness" criteria and 0% overall mark.

Answer (score 7):

#### Mathematical correctness

The used approach is incorrect for very large numbers, here is an
example:

```
let i = 4611686014132420400
print(Double(i).squareRoot().rounded() == Double(i).squareRoot())
// true
```

The output is `true`, even if the number is not a perfect square:
\$ \sqrt{4611686014132420400} \approx 2147483646.9999999513383954536814215918 \$.

The reason is that a `Double` (which is a 64-bit floating point number
according to the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)
standard) has only 53 bits for the "significand", therefore precision
is lost in the conversion `Double(i)`.

It also fails for negative numbers:

```
let i = -16
print(Double(i).squareRoot().rounded() == Double(i).squareRoot())
// false
```

because `(-16.0).squareRoot()` is `NaN` ("not a number").

But for non-negative numbers below \$ 2^{52} \$, your approach should
be correct.

#### Swiftyness

`arr` is not mutated, therefore it should be a *constant* (with `let`):

```
let arr = Array(4...17)
```

But actually it is not needed to create an array with all numbers in 
the given range. You can iterate over a range directly:

```
let range = 4...17
for i in range { ... }
```

Even better, move the calculation into a separate function:

```
func numberOfPerfectSquares(in range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    for i in range {
        if Double(i).squareRoot().rounded() == Double(i).squareRoot(){
            count += 1
        }
    }
    return count
}

print(numberOfPerfectSquares(in: 4...17))
```

That allows you to add test cases, for example:

```
assert(numberOfPerfectSquares(in: 0...0) == 1)
assert(numberOfPerfectSquares(in: 100...10_000) == 91)
assert(numberOfPerfectSquares(in: 101...10_000) == 90)
assert(numberOfPerfectSquares(in: 101...9_999) == 89)
// ...

// More test cases if negative input is allowed:
assert(numberOfPerfectSquares(in: -10...10) == 9)
assert(numberOfPerfectSquares(in: -10_000...-100) == 91)
// ...
```

This is extremely useful to check the correctness if you changed the implementation.

#### Performance

Poor. Your code checks *every* number in the range if it is a perfect
square or not. It is far more efficient to iterate over the possible square roots:

```
func numberOfPerfectSquares(in range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    var i = Int(Double(range.lowerBound).squareRoot())
    while i * i < range.lowerBound {
        i += 1
    }
    while i * i <= range.upperBound {
        count += 1
        i += 1
    }
    return count
}
```

This is already much faster, but you don't need a loop at all!  It suffices to
compute the number of perfect squares below the lower resp. upper bound, and return
the difference:

```
func numberOfPerfectSquares(in range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    // Number of perfect squares < lower bound:
    let lo = range.lowerBound == 0 ? 0 : Int(Double(range.lowerBound - 1).squareRoot()) + 1
    // Number of perfect squares <= upper bound:
    let hi = Int(Double(range.upperBound).squareRoot()) + 1
    return hi - lo
}
```

Note that this still does not work for negative numbers and numbers above \$ 2^{52} \$
due to the rounding errors. For the latter problem, see [Computing the integer square root of large numbers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177923/computing-the-integer-square-root-of-large-numbers).

Comment: Martin I want to be like you when I grow up :P

Comment: thank you so much for the feedback. There are more things to learn for me. I hope i can get to where you are Martin

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the Swift array methods (`map`, `filter`, ...)

```
let arr = Array(4...17)
let result= arr.filter{$0.squareRoot().rounded == $0.squareRoot()}.count
print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.