# Computing the integer square root of large numbers

Tags: swift, integer, floating-point

The ["integer square root"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) of a
non-negative integer \$ n \$ is defined as the largest *integer* not greater than
 \$ \sqrt{n} \$:
$$
 \operatorname{isqrt}(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor
 = \max \{ k \in \Bbb N_0 \mid k^2 \le n \}
$$
It is for example needed in prime factorization, as an upper bound for the possible 
factors.

A simple approach is to compute the floating point square root and truncate the result to an integer. In Swift that would be

```
func isqrt_simple(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(Double(n).squareRoot())
}
```

As observed in 
[Computing the square root of a 64-bit integer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69069/computing-the-square-root-of-a-64-bit-integer),
this can produce wrong results for large numbers, because an IEEE 64-bit floating point
number with its 53 bit significand cannot represent large integers exactly.
Here is an example:

```
let n = 9223371982334239233
let r = isqrt_simple(n)

print(r)           // 3037000491
print(r * r <= n)  // false
```

The correct result would be 3037000490, since
$$
  \sqrt{9223371982334239233} \approx 3037000490.9999996957524364127605120353
$$
(computed with PARI/GP).

The following implementation uses the ideas from 
[DarthGizka's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69502/35991)
to the above mentioned question to implement a "correct" integer square root function in **Swift 4:**

```
func isqrt(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    precondition(n >= 0, "argument of isqrt() must be non-negative")

    var r = Int(Double(n).squareRoot()) // Initial approximation
    // Try to increase:
    while case let prod = r.multipliedReportingOverflow(by: r),
        !prod.overflow && prod.partialValue < n  {
            r += 1
    }
    // Decrease if necessary:
    while case let prod = r.multipliedReportingOverflow(by: r),
        prod.overflow || prod.partialValue > n  {
            r -= 1
    }
    return r
}
```

Example:

```
let n = 9223371982334239233
let r = isqrt(n)

print(r)                 // 3037000490
print(r * r <= n)        // true
print((r+1) * (r+1) > n) // true
```

Remarks:

- I have chosen `Int` as argument and result type even if the square root is defined
  only for non-negative integers. The reason is that `Int` is the prevalent integer
  type in Swift and already used for quantities that can not be negative (e.g.
  the `count` of an array, or the `MemoryLayout<T>.size` of a type).
- `Int` can be a 32-bit or 64-bit quantity, therefore I cannot check against
  a constant for overflow (as `r < UINT32_MAX` in 
  [DarthGizka's C++ solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69502/35991)).
  `multipliedReportingOverflow()` is used instead to check if squaring a candidate causes an overflow.

The code worked correctly in all my tests. Here are some tests which all succeed

```
func testSqrt(_ n: Int) {
    let r = isqrt(n)
    if r * r > n {
        print("Too large:", n, r)
    } else if (r+1) * (r+1) <= n {
        print("Too small:", n, r)
    }
}

testSqrt(4503599761588224)
testSqrt(4503599895805955)
testSqrt(4503600030023688)
testSqrt(4503600164241423)

testSqrt(9223371982334241080)
testSqrt(9223371982334239233)
testSqrt(9223372024852248003)
testSqrt(9223372024852247041)
testSqrt(9223372030926249000)
testSqrt(9223372030926247424)
```

These tests fail if `isqrt_simple()` is used instead.

All feedback is welcome, in particular suggestions how to improve the performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is rather unnecessary. When converted to double, all 64-bit integers retain 1 sign bit and at least 52 precision bits. So the error is at most 11 bit; which means for any number *N*, the error $$dN<=\frac{2^{11}}{2^{63}}N=2^{-52}N$$
With simple calculus, the error of sqrt() is $$d(\sqrt{N})=\frac{dN}{2\sqrt{N}}<=\frac{2^{-52}N}{2\sqrt{N}}=2^{-53}\sqrt{N}<2^{-53}*2^{32}=2^{-21}<<1$$
In any case the error must be smaller than 1. With rounding/truncation, it can only be -1, 0, or 1.

So your code can be

```
func isqrt(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    var r = Int(Double(n).squareRoot()) // Initial approximation
    if r * r > n { r -= 1 }
    else if (r + 1) * (r + 1) <= n { r += 1}
    return r
}
```

**edit:**
There will be time that `(r + 1) * (r + 1)` be larger than `Int.max` and causes error. Instead of using `multipliedReportingOverflow`, I would do it this way

```
func isqrt(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if n >= 3037000499 * 3037000499 {return 3037000499}
    var r = Int(Double(n).squareRoot()) // Initial approximation
    if r * r > n { r -= 1 }
    else if (r + 1) * (r + 1) <= n { r += 1}
    return r
}
```

**edit 2:**
To deal with different possible `Int` sizes:

```
func isqrt(_ n: Int) -> Int {
  #if arch(i386) || arch(arm)
    if n >= 46340 * 46340 {return 46340}
  #else
    if n >= 3037000499 * 3037000499 {return 3037000499}
  #endif

  var r = Int(Double(n).squareRoot()) // Initial approximation
  if r * r > n { r -= 1 }
  else if (r + 1) * (r + 1) <= n { r += 1}
  return r
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and analysis. There is one problem though: `(r + 1) * (r + 1)` can overflow. As an example, `isqrt(Int.max)` will crash at runtime with your suggested implementation.

Comment: Swift has a `&*` operator which silently discards overflow (similar to what `*` does in other languages). But then `isqrt(Int.max)` would return 3037000500, which is one too large.

Comment: @MartinR I guess that's because you are using signed integers. Casting both r and n as unsigned and you should be good.

Comment: @MartinR See my new changes.

Comment: Int can be a 32-bit or 64-bit integer in Swift, that's why I wanted to avoid checking against a constant (compare remark #2 in my question). – Using UInt for intermediate results would be an option, I'll check that later.

Comment: @MartinR  I believe the size of `Int` is determined by the compiler, so you can use `__LP64__` to handle both. See my changes.

Comment: It *is* possible to conditionally compile dependent on the word size, but `#if __LP64__` does not work, the if-branch is never taken. Here https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Runtime.swift.gyb#L204 is an example how that is currently done in the Swift source code.

Comment: @MartinR I love the Never actually code in Swift. Not even sizeof()?

Comment: (My pleasure to help!)

Answer (score -1):

don't want to be an ass here, but in your case all the heavy lifting is actually done by `Int(Double(n).squareRoot())` which is implemented in Swift standard library (I suppose, not a swift programmer my self). All **your** code does is actually +-1, so there's not much field for performance improvement I suppose.
Generally in order to improve performance, you need to optimize the most time consuming operation, so in this case you'd have to reimplement `Double(n).squareRoot()` or implement custom sqr root method for integer, maybe based on some integer numerical approximation methods.
Last but not least - this forum is IMHO rather for code style / quality review, your question rather belongs to stackoverflow.com, it's more popular so you might expect more feedback there.

Comment: Performance questions *are* on-topic (compare [help/on-topic]), and I did not restrict my question to that aspect (*"All feedback is welcome ..."*)

Comment: Not saying they are off-topic, just saying you might get better feedback at SO as, like I said, your actual code does not do much work so there's not much to optimize / review here. Now, if you wrote your own sqrt implementation, that might be very nice too look at and comment of performance and stuff.

Comment: `isqrt` is slower than `isqrt_simple` by a factor of about 3, so the extra work (2 multiplications with overflow check) is relevant. Reducing that factor would be nice.