# Find index of array item starting at a given location

Tags: swift

I've written a lot of C++ but now I'm learning Swift.  I did an exercise, the standard Sieve of Erastosthenes. It works fine, but it seems a bit clunky and I wonder if I'm missing some language features that might streamline it a bit and make it more idiomatic Swift.

Here's the code:

```
struct Sieve {
    let primes: [Int]
    init(_ maxValue: Int) {
        var numbers = Array<Int?>(repeating: nil, count:maxValue + 1)
        for n in 2...maxValue { numbers[n] = n }
        var start = 2
        while start < maxValue {
            guard let prime = numbers.first(where: {$0 != nil && $0! >= start}) else {break}
            let lo = 2 * prime!
            if lo < maxValue {
                for x in stride(from: lo, to: numbers.count, by: prime!) {
                    numbers[x] = nil
                }
            }
            start = prime! + 1
        }
        primes = numbers.compactMap{$0}
    }
}
```

With the line starting "guard let prime", I'd like to supply a starting index for the 'find' operation, which would be a lot more efficient and would let me drop the comparison `$0! >= start` altogether. Something along the lines of

```
guard let prime = numbers.first(where: {$0 != nil}, start: start) else {break}
```

I also tried

```
guard let prime = (start...maxValue).first(where: {index in numbers[index] != nil}) else {break}
```

and that does work but it seems even more awkward. It does have the advantage of starting the search at the index `start` instead of index zero each time. What's the preferred way to search an array beginning somewhere in the middle of it?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: (One reference site is [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Swift).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your immediate question: You can search in an array *slice:*

```
 guard let prime = numbers[start...].first(where: {$0 != nil}) else {break}
```

That works because array slices share their indices with the originating array.

---

There is a small bug in your program, as one can see here:

```
let sieve = Sieve(4)
print(sieve.primes) // [2, 3, 4]
```

The reason is that the

```
if lo < maxValue { ... }
```

loop does not include the last value. The test should be `lo <= maxValue`.

---

There are also some possible improvements:

```
        let lo = 2 * prime!
```

can be replaced by

```
        let lo = prime! * prime!
```

because all lower multiples have been “nilled” before. As a consequence, the outer loop

```
    while start <= maxValue { ... }
```

can be replaced by

```
    while start * start <= maxValue { ... }
```

Now instead of repeatedly searching for the next non-nil entry in the array you might as well *iterate* over the array. This allows also to get rid of the ugly forced unwrapping `prime!`:

```
    for i in (2..<numbers.count).prefix(while: { $0 * $0 <= maxValue }) {
        if numbers[i] != nil {
            for x in stride(from: i * i, to: numbers.count, by: i) {
                numbers[x] = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

At this point it becomes apparent that the information in the `numbers` array is redundant: Each element is equal to its index or `nil`. Therefore  a *boolean* array is sufficient instead of an array of optional integers, this reduces the required memory considerably.

I suggest that you first try to implement that yourself, otherwise have a look at `func eratosthenesSieve()` in [Prime Number Generator & Efficiency](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192021/prime-number-generator-efficiency/192042#192042).

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, and for pointing out that bug. I had rather hastily inserted that `if` statement when I found that the invocation of `stride` threw an exception when `lo >= numbers.count`. The (now deprecated) older form of the `for` loop, `for x = lo; x < numbers.count; x += prime` simply would have executed zero times in that case.