# Faster Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: performance, primes, swift, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes :

- It takes advantages of the fact that all primes from 5 and above can be written as [`6X-1` or `6X+1`](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html),
- For better space complexity, it uses a pretty accurate `upperbound`. Better estimations of the upper bound can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442.pdf). I've observed a very slight increase in performance with this.

---

```
func eratosthenesSieve(to n: Int) -> [Int] {

    guard 2 <= n else { return [] }

    var composites = Array(repeating: false, count: n + 1)
    var primes: [Int] = []
    let d = Double(n)
    let upperBound = Int((d / log(d)) * (1.0 + 1.2762/log(d)))
    primes.reserveCapacity(upperBound)
    let squareRootN = Int(d.squareRoot())

    //2 and 3
    var p = 2
    let twoOrThree = min(n, 3)
    while p <= twoOrThree {
        primes.append(p)
        var q = p * p
        let step = p * (p - 1)
        while q <= n {
            composites[q] = true
            q += step
        }
        p += 1
    }

    //5 and above
    p += 1
    while p <= squareRootN {
        for i in 0..<2 {
            let nbr = p + 2 * i
            if !composites[nbr] {
                primes.append(nbr)
                var q = nbr * nbr
                var coef = 2 * (i + 1)
                while q <= n  {
                    composites[q] = true
                    q += coef * nbr
                    coef = 6 - coef
                }
            }
        }
        p += 6
    }

    while p <= n {
        for i in 0..<2 {
            let nbr = p + 2 * i
            if nbr <= n && !composites[nbr] {
                primes.append(nbr)
            }
        }
        p += 6
    }

    return primes
}
```

---

It was inspired by [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/192042/49921) code by [Mr Martin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/35991/martin-r).

Using the same benchmarking code in that answer, adding a fourth fractional digit in the timing results, plus some formatting, here are the results :

```
        ---------------------------------------------------------------
        |                |       Nbr   |          Time (sec)          | 
        |      Up to     |        of   |------------------------------|
        |                |    Primes   |   Martin's   |      This     |
        |----------------|-------------|------------------------------|
        |        100_000 |        9592 |       0.0008 |        0.0004 |
        |----------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
        |      1_000_000 |      78_498 |       0.0056 |        0.0026 |
        |----------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
        |     10_000_000 |     664_579 |       0.1233 |        0.0426 |
        |----------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
        |    100_000_000 |   5_761_455 |       1.0976 |        0.5089 |
        |----------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
        |  1_000_000_000 |  50_847_534 |      12.1328 |        5.9759 |
        |----------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
        | 10_000_000_000 | 455_052_511 |     165.5658 |       84.5477 |
        |----------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
```

Using [Attabench](https://github.com/attaswift/Attabench), here is a visual representation of the performance of both codes while `n` is less than `2^16`:

[image: Attabench results]

---

One thing I observe is some elements in the `composites` array are marked with `true` multiple times. This is expected (but unwanted) behavior since `6X-1` or `6X+1` aren't all primes.

What I'm looking for is making **this** Sieve of Eratosthenes quicker. I'm well aware of faster methods of finding primes.

Naming, code clarity, conciseness, consistency, etc, are welcome but are **not** the main point here.

Answer (score 1):

> It takes advantages of the fact that all primes from 5 and above can be written as 6X-1 or 6X+1,

I don't think it does, really. It structures the code around that fact, but to take advantage of it, *at a minimum* you should replace

> ```
>     while p <= twoOrThree {
>         primes.append(p)
>         var q = p * p
>         let step = p * (p - 1)
>         while q <= n {
>             composites[q] = true
>             q += step
>         }
>         p += 1
>     }
> ```

with

```
    while p <= twoOrThree {
        primes.append(p)
        p += 1
    }
```

which in my testing gives a significant speedup.

---

To maximise the advantage, you could reduce `composites` to only store flags for \$6X \pm 1\$. Proof of concept code (could be tidier):

```
    var pidx = 1
    p = 5
    while p <= squareRootN {
        if !composites[pidx] {
            primes.append(p)

            var qidx = 3 * pidx * (pidx + 2) + 1 + (pidx & 1)
            let delta = p << 1
            let off = (4 - 2 * (pidx & 1)) * pidx + 1
            while qidx < composites.count {
                composites[qidx - off] = true
                composites[qidx] = true
                qidx += delta
            }
            if qidx - off < composites.count {
                composites[qidx - off] = true
            }
        }

        pidx += 1
        p += 2 + 2 * (pidx & 1)
    }

    while p <= n {
        if !composites[pidx] { primes.append(p) }
        pidx += 1
        p += 2 + 2 * (pidx & 1)
    }
```

This gives a moderate speedup in my testing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/ExAniDF) are the benchmarks, and they favor the code in the question (`original` being Martin's, and `eratosthenes2` is the code in your answer). Attabench confirms the benchmarks.

Comment: @Carpsen90, I don't know Swift and there seem to be some subtleties around imports which both this question and the answer you reference brush under the table, but I compared a tweaked version of your code with my code on https://tio.run/ . [Full tested code](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/73e47998812e65b1e1a21df3ec70c07f). I see user time: 12.470 s for your code and 7.002 s for mine. tio.run isn't ideal for benchmarking, but that's a significant improvement.

Comment: (I suspect the problem is that you've benchmarked my code sieving three times as far as your code).

Comment: The benchmarks were correct and can still be reproduced. You didn't mention in your answer this line `var composites = Array(repeating: false, count: n / 3 + 1)`, which makes all the difference. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/qLi7p8M) are the new benchmarks which favor your code.

Comment: The answer is intended to be a code review, not a patch.